# Retrieving only PRINT command from SQL Server procedure in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I apologize if I am missing a few things here, I am still learning .NET.

I have a project I have been working on where I am restoring a database as well as transaction logs. After each transaction log I have a PRINT statement to output that the transaction log has been processed.

I have been using the `OnInfoMessage` function to get the messages out of what is done in SQL Server, but was looking to ONLY extract the PRINT command out of it and display it in a textbox / label / RichTextBox as sort of a status box that updates as it goes.

My procedure in SQL Server is as follows

```
....
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
  SET @sql = 'RESTORE LOG FCS FROM DISK = ''C:\Databases\'+@fileName     +'''  WITH NORECOVERY';
EXEC (@sql);
PRINT '===' +@sql;
FETCH NEXT FROM cFile INTO @fileName
END
CLOSE cFile
DEALLOCATE cFile
```

In VB.net I am able to get ALL messages to display in a log file.

```
Private Shared Sub OnInfoMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)

    Using LogFile As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\SDBT\worklog.ft", True)

        LogFile.WriteLine(e.Message)

    End Using
End Sub
```

This in turn gives me the following output...

```
Processed 10392 pages for database 'FCS', file 'FCS' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'FCS', file 'FCS_log' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 10394 pages in 2.652 seconds  (30.619 MB/sec).
Processed 0 pages for database 'FCS', file 'FCS' on file 1.
Processed 6 pages for database 'FCS', file 'FCS_log' on file 1.
RESTORE LOG successfully processed 6 pages in 0.061 seconds (0.720 MB/sec).
===RESTORE LOG FCS FROM DISK = 'C:\SDBT_TestDB\log_00001.trn'  WITH NORECOVERY
Processed 0 pages for database 'FCS', file 'FCS' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'FCS', file 'FCS_log' on file 1.
RESTORE LOG successfully processed 2 pages in 0.058 seconds (0.252 MB/sec).
===RESTORE LOG FCS FROM DISK = 'C:\SDBT_TestDB\log_00002.trn'  WITH NORECOVERY
```

Ideally I would like to only retrieve the lines preceded with "===" and output those to the user.

Is it possible to get the `@sql` variable value from SQL Server to VB.net or is there something built into .NET that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OnInfoMessage` sub, check each line of text in `e.Message` to see if it starts with `===` and only write those lines.

```
    For Each line In e.Message.Split(vbNewLine)
        If(line.StartsWith("===")) Then
             LogFile.WriteLine(line)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Now to get it to show up in a textbox as it completes step by step and im good to go! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answe‌​r-work) if you feel it was useful to you.