# Updating Textbox based off SQL InfoMessages results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, backgroundworker

Branching off a previous question... [Retrieving only PRINT command from SQL Server procedure in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523468/retrieving-only-print-command-from-sql-server-procedure-in-vb-net)

I was able to dump all the text from SQL Server's messages and use what I need but for some reason I am unable to update my textbox with the events.

```
    Private Shared Sub OnInfoMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)


    Dim Counter As Integer

    Counter = 1

    For Each line In e.Message.Split(vbNewLine)

        If (line.Contains("====")) Then

            RestoreTool.txtTRNStatus.Text = "TRN #" & Counter & "Restored"

            Using LogFile As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\SDBT\worklog.ft", True)

                LogFile.WriteLine(line)

            End Using


            Counter += 1

        End If
    Next
```

Everything runs smoothly but the textbox (txtTRNStatus) does not update with anything and remains blank (Where it should be showing "TRN #1 Restored")

I am utilizing a Background Worker as well to call the procedure that actually performs the restoration of a database. That procedure is what contains the event handler for the SQLInfoMessages.

```
 Dim SQL As SqlCommand
    Dim DBConn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

    SQL = New SqlCommand(DBScript, DBConn)

    AddHandler DBConn.InfoMessage, New SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(AddressOf OnInfoMessage)

 Dim SQLResult As IAsyncResult = SQL.BeginExecuteNonQuery()


    Try

    Catch e As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(e.Message)

    End Try

    SQL.EndExecuteNonQuery(SQLResult)



    CompletedTask = True


    DBConn.Close()
```

I have a feeling the only way I can get the text to update is through the addition of something in the `DoWork()` portion of the Backgroundworker but cannot figure out what exactly. Can the OnInfoMessages be called at will when an update is needed or is it only specific to where the Event Handler is?

[image: Restoration Tool]

As you can see in the image, It's during the actual "restoration" that the tool would normally report which transaction log has been restored based off of the SQL Message received but it remains blank...

Thank you once again!

EDIT: My progress update for my background worker is set up correctly, I just am having trouble calling events from the OnInfoMessage Sub as a progress update which is where gets the next line from SQL.

Comment: It sounds like you are making cross-thread GUI updates.  Try using `Invoke` when updating the `TextBox` - something like `RestoreTool.txtTRNStatus.Invoke(Sub() RestoreTool.txtTRNStatus.Text = "TRN #" & Counter & "Restored")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the backgroundworker properly. In the "doWork" there must not have any line of code that affect the UI(UserInterface) as this thread isn't the main thread of the application. If it does, it will either crash or do nothing.

So if you need to change the UI from the background worker you will need to tell the main thread to do so from the "DoWork" method. This can be achieved by hooking a callback to event "ProgressChanged" of your backgroundWorker object.

```
 ' This event handler updates the UI. '
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged( _
ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
Handles backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

    Me.txtTRNStatus.Text = e.UserState.ToString()//Update UI

End Sub
```

From the "DoWork" method, raise this event like shown below to tell main thread to update UI. Use the second parameter to pass whatever is needed by main thread to do so.

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
   ' This method will run on a thread other than the UI thread. '
   ' Be sure not to manipulate any Windows Forms controls created' 
   ' on the UI thread from this method.'

   Dim SomeObject As [Object]
   //some stuff
   backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(1, SomeObject)
   //some stuff
   backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(2, SomeObject)

 End Sub
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for more detail on backgroundworker usage.

Or you could just use "invoke" like @Mark suggested in the comment. This tell main thread execute a sub. As long as the UI update is done by the main thread you will be fine.